# How can I read HDF5 file? Getting Invalid argument error

Tags: hdf5, oserror

I am trying to read a HDF5 file, but following error is displayed. How to fix it?

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'E:    rain_catvnoncat.h5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Comment: ```'E:    rain_catvnoncat.h5'``` doesn't look like a valid file name. Did you try to write ```E:\rain_catvnoncat.h5``` but forgot to escape the ```\```?

Comment: Looks like a filename error. Which language? If Python, which package?